# Singly Linked List merge list

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I have a method that takes in two generic type Singly Link lists the purpose of the method is to merge the two Singly Link lists into a single new list. But the new list cannot have duplicate values. My code already creates the merged list but it won't remove the duplicate item. There seems to be an issue with the removal part of the code in System.out.println("duplicate:) this part shows that the while loop found a duplicate item but it will not remove. Can some one help me out?

```
 //@ param mergeList method combines two Singly Linked lists into one while also removing any duplicate elements. (Incomplete will not remove dupilcates.)
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> SinglyLinkedList<T>  mergeLists(SinglyLinkedList<T> list1, SinglyLinkedList<T> list2) {
   
    //new list to merge both parameter lists
    SinglyLinkedList<T> fin = new SinglyLinkedList<>();
    
    //node variables pointers
    SLLNode temp;
    SLLNode l1 = list1.getHead();
    SLLNode l2 = list2.getHead();
    
    //while loop to traverse list 1 and add to fin list
    while(l1 != null){
        temp = l1;
        fin.append(temp);
        l1 = l1.getNext();
    }//close while
    
    //While loop to traverse list 2 and add to fin list
    while(l2 != null){
        temp = l2;
        fin.append(temp);
        l2 = l2.getNext();
    }//close while
    
    //start of duplicate removal
    
    //create node variables and new no duplicate link list
    SLLNode removaltemp = null ,removaltemp2 = null ,  duplicate = null;
    SLLNode pointer= null;
    SinglyLinkedList<T> last = new SinglyLinkedList<>();
    
    //Set Nodes
    removaltemp = fin.getHead();
    pointer = fin.getHead();
    last.append(pointer);
    
    //while loop to check head with body
    while(removaltemp!= null){
        removaltemp2 = removaltemp;
      System.out.println("Hello");

        //while loop to check body with head
        while(removaltemp2.getNext() != null ){
      System.out.println("Hi");
            
            //if statement for element removal
            if(removaltemp.getData().equals(removaltemp2.getNext().getData())){
             System.out.println("duplicate");
                duplicate = removaltemp2.getNext();
                removaltemp2 = removaltemp2.getNext().getNext();
                System.gc();
                
            }// close if
            
            //if not duplicate
            else if(removaltemp2 != removaltemp2.getNext()) {
               removaltemp2 = removaltemp2.getNext();
               
            }//close else if
        }//close nested while loop
        
        //assign next head to loop
        pointer= pointer.getNext();
        removaltemp = removaltemp.getNext();
        
    }//close while loop
    
    //return statement
    return last;
}//close merge method
```

Comment: Can you explain how you *think* your code is removing the duplicate?

Comment: Yes, The way I put is is  removaltemp2 = removaltemp2.getNext().getNext(); by skipping the .getNext() and connecting to the NextNext

Comment: How does changing a variable change anything in the list?

Comment: Makes sense, should I then use for example removaltemp2 append an item to the list and when it is a duplicate just skip? would that work?